# In simplistic terms, what is Client Business Logic & a Business Entity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, repository

as the question states -  what is Client Business Logic & a Business Entity?

Answer (score 0):

**Client Business Logic**
The part of an application program that performs the required data processing of the business. It refers to the routines that perform the data entry, update, query and report processing, and more specifically to the processing that takes place behind the scenes rather than the presentation logic required to display the data on the screen (GUI processing). Client applications are made up of a user interface and business logic. Server applications are mostly business logic.

**Business Entity**
That the accounting records reflect the financial activities of a specific corporate entity, separate and distinct from the people who finance it or work in it. It is one of the 'ground rules' of accounting, see accounting concepts for the others.